# Circle spline with CINEMA4D

Tags: cinema4d

I'm having a very basic issue. Whenever I try to create a circle (spline)... it doesn't come out rounded, but "angular"! Even if I increase the number of points it doesn't change. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a circle spline it's definite it's a circle.
Maybe it's a monitor resolution thing. If the circle
In an office I worked some years ago I noticed that circle objects I created in Corel where not perfect circles. It had to do with the monitor.